# Jest: cannot find module required inside module to be tested (relative path)

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, reactjs, jestjs

I have this component:

```
import React from 'react';
import VideoTag from './VideoTag';
import JWPlayer from './JWPlayer';

class VideoWrapper extends React.Component {
//... component code
}
```

That based on some logic renders another component inside ( VideoTag or JWPlayer) but when I try to test it in a jest file i get the error:

**Cannot find module './VideoTag'**

The three coponents are in the same directory that's why it actually works when I transpile it and see it in action in a browser but looks like Jest is having problems resolving those relative paths, this is the jest file:

```
jest.dontMock('../src/shared/components/Video/VideoWrapper.jsx');

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
TestUtils from 'react-addons-test-utils';

import VideoWrapper from '../src/shared/components/Video/VideoWrapper.jsx';

describe('VideoWrapper tests', () => {
  it('Render JWPlayer', () => {

      let vWrapper = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
      < VideoWrapper model={model} />
  );

  });
});
```

The error is at line:

```
import VideoWrapper from '../src/shared/components/Video/VideoWrapper.jsx';
```

How do I tell jest how to handle relative paths?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem were not the paths, It was looking for modules only with .js extension, it worked after adding the .jsx in the jest configuration:

```
"moduleFileExtensions": [
  "js",
  "jsx"
]
```

Answer (score 15):

I also had to add the `moduleNameMapper` to my jest configuration for my tsconfig path maps in order to get my tests to recognize the path maps I had setup. Something like this:

```
"moduleNameMapper": {
      "^yourPath/(.*)": "<rootDir>\\yourPath\\$1"
    }
```

Hopefully this will help someone down the line!

Comment: This just saved me, thank you!!!

I had multiple libraries locally with `tsconfig` managing their `paths` and I guess `jest` or `typescript` wasn't mapping the module imports correctly for source files (even though it worked fine for imports in the test files).

Comment: If you could provide an example, it would be awesome

Comment: @JoãoIgnacio suppose you are importing this in your original js file `import * as Components from '/static/myApp/js/components.js'`. Then in moduleNameWrapper you will have the following: `"^/static/myApp/js/(.*)": "<rootDir>/myProject/myApp/static/myApp/js/$1"`. Please note I am using a Django project and app as an example. See how **/static/myApp/js/** is placed in the moduleNameWrapper

Comment: Note that if you run `jest --watch` and then start editing the jest config, it seems to pick it up and re-run, but it is not actually reloading the config. Just use plain `jest` and invoke manually while working this out.

Answer (score 2):

In my case the issue was the `import` is also case sensitive. Check your `import` statement and ensure that it matches the filename exactly!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add moduleFileExtensions in the configuration for these two options since jest uses ['js', 'jsx', 'json', 'node'] as default file extensions. (Unless you want to specifically skip any option that is)

Answer (score 0):

For others ending up here trying to use Jest with TypeScript: you need to include `ts` in the `moduleFileExtensions`, e.g.:

```
"moduleFileExtensions": [
  "js",
  "jsx",
  "json",
  "node",
  "ts"
]
```

You also need a transform for `*.ts` files:

```
transform: {
  "^.+\\.vue$": "vue-jest",
  "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest",
  "^.+\\.(ts|tsx)$": "ts-jest"
},
```